# Solve the equation $3x^2+2y^2-4xy+x-2=0$ in the set of integer numbers.

Tags: polynomials, square-numbers

**QUESTION**

Solve the equation $3x^2+2y^2-4xy+x-2=0$ in the set of integer numbers.

**MY IDEA**

I decided to write it as:

> $2x^2+2y^2-4xy+x^2+x-2=0={(x\sqrt{2}+y\sqrt{2})}^2+x^2+x-2$

I was thinking of writing $x^2+x-2$ as a perfect square, but I don't know.

Another way might be writing all the equations as a perfect square, which means it should equal $0$.

I'm not that good at this type of problem and I wonder if one of you can explain how you can solve this problem?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you, but I don't understand. I don't know the quadric equation. Can you explain the idea without using it?

Comment: If you don't know how to solve a quadratic equation, then you should not post yet, and first learn it. See for example [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation). This is taught in highschool.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I found it in a book for 7th grade. Thank you so much, anyways!

Comment: You dropped a sign-the $y \sqrt 2$ term should be negative.  It would be cleaner to write $2(x-y)^2$  Then note that the square is always nonnegative, so $x^2+x-2$ must be negative.  That doesn't allow many values of $x$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Can you explain how you got $y=0$ or $y=1$ with the equation: $-8y^2-8y+25$, p;ease?

Comment: $2x^2 + 2y^2 - 4xy = 2(x - y)^2$  
$x^2 + x - 2 = (x + 2)(x -1)$   
$2(x - y)^2 + (x + 2)(x - 1) = 0$

Comment: @DietrichBurde:  I said that $x^2+x-2$ had to be negative and it is in your solution

Comment: @RossMillikan I am sorry, too late already here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have

$$2(x - y)^2 = 2 - x^2 - x \implies (x - y)^2 = 1 - \dfrac{x(x+1)}{2}.$$

This implies that $1 - x(x+1)/2$ is a perfect square. Since the term $x(x+1)/2$ is always non-negative, then either $(x-y)^2 = 1 - 0 = 1$ or $(x-y)^2 = 1 - 1 = 0$ by means of $x = 0$ or $x = -1$ for the first case, or $x = 1$ or $x = -2$ for the second case. Those values for $x$ yield the solutions
$$(x,y) \in \{(-2,-2), (-1,-2), (-1,0), (0,-1), (0,1), (1,1)\}.$$

Comment: Thank you sooo much! I dont understand why $x(x+1)/2$ is non-negative. Thank you again!

Comment: @IonelaBuciu It's because either $x = 0$ or $x+1 = 0$ (in which case $x(x+1) = 0$), or both $x$ and $x+1$ have the same sign (in which case $x(x+1) > 0$).

Comment: @DarthGeek, I like your answer very much (+1).

Answer (score 4):

Solving the quadratic equation $3x^2+(1-4y)x+2y^2-2=0$ in $x$, we obtain the discriminant
$$
D=-8y^2-8y+25
$$
which needs to be a square. Hence in particular $D\ge 0$. This is equivalent to $y=1,0,-1,-2$.

Answer (score 2):

$3x^2+2y^2-4xy+x-2=0
$

$2y^2-4xy+3x^2+x-2=0
$

$\begin{array}\\
d
&=16x^2-4\cdot 2(3x^2+x-2)\\
&=16x^2-24x^2-8x+16\\
&=-8x^2-8x+16\\
&=-8(x^2+x-2)\\
&=-8(x+2)(x-1)\\
&=-2(4x^2+4x-8)\\
&=-2(4x^2+4x+1-9)\\
&=-2((2x+1)^2-9)\\
\end{array}
$

Since we want $d \ge 0$,
$(2x+1)^2 \le 9$
so
$-3 \le 2x+1 \le 3
$
or
$-2 \le x \le 1$.

$d(-2, -1, 0, 1)
=(0, 16, 16, 0)
$
so the integer values
for which $d$ is square are
$x=-2,-1, 0, 1$
for which

$\begin{array}\\
y(x=-2, -1, 0, 1)
&=\dfrac{4x\pm \sqrt{d(x)}}{4}\\
&=(-2, -1, 0, 1)\pm (0, 1, 1, 0)\\
&=(-2, (-2, 0), (-1, 1), 1)\\
\end{array}
$

so
$(x, y)
=(-2, -2), (-1, -2), (-1, 0),
(0, -1), (0, 1), (1, 1)
$.

Answer (score 2):

$3x^2 + 2y^2 - 4xy + x - 2 = 2(x - y)^2 + (x + 2)(x - 1) = 0$

$2(x - y)^2 = 0$ AND $(x + 2)(x - 1) = 0$
$x = y$ AND $x = -2$ or $x = 1$
So, $ y = -2$ or $y = 1$

For the other solutions, solve:
$2(x - y)^2 = - (x + 2)(x - 1)$

So,

1. $x < -2$ AND $x > 1$   Impossible!!
2. $x > -2$ AND $x < 1$ So, $x = -1$ or $x = 0$

Solving for $y$, we get $y = -1$ (for $x = -1$) and we get $y = 0$ (for $x = 0$)

The solution set is $\{-2, -1, 0, 1\}$