# How to calculate the min and max points of an ellipse

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, analytic-geometry

The question is inspired by: [Solve the equation $3x^2+2y^2-4xy+x-2=0$ in the set of integer numbers.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4774329/solve-the-equation-3x22y2-4xyx-2-0-in-the-set-of-integer-numbers#comment10143600_4774329).

The first way to solve the equation is by solving the quadratic equation for $x$ - $x_{1,2}=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$ and then we know that $x$ is an integer so the $\Delta$  has to be a perfect square, and from there you can easily get the answer. I thought of another way:
What if we calculate the min and max point of the equation and then we will take the y's integers in that range, and then calculate the x's and from there, we will take the $(x,y)$ which are integers.  I thought that maybe the canonic version of the equation might help, so I calculated it:

> The matrix describing the square part is $A=\begin{pmatrix}3&-2 \\ -2&2\end{pmatrix}$.
> The linear vector is $J=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ and the free variable is $h=-2$.
> We can calculate that:
> $\begin{pmatrix}3&-2 \\ -2&2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{-1-\sqrt{17}}{\sqrt{34+2\sqrt{17}}} & \frac{\sqrt{17}-1}{\sqrt{34-2\sqrt{17}}}\\ \frac{4}{\sqrt{34+2\sqrt{17}}}& \frac{4}{\sqrt{34-2\sqrt{17}}}\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}\frac{5+\sqrt{17}}{2}&0\\ 0&\frac{5-\sqrt{17}}{2}\end{pmatrix}\cdot{\begin{pmatrix}\frac{-1-\sqrt{17}}{\sqrt{34+2\sqrt{17}}} & \frac{\sqrt{17}-1}{\sqrt{34-2\sqrt{17}}}\\ \frac{4}{\sqrt{34+2\sqrt{17}}}& \frac{4}{\sqrt{34-2\sqrt{17}}}\end{pmatrix}}^t$
> We will write that: $A=QDQ^{t}$. And,  $\begin{pmatrix} u\\v \end{pmatrix}=Q\cdot\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}$.
> $\begin{pmatrix}u& v\end{pmatrix}\cdot D\cdot \begin{pmatrix}u\\ v\end{pmatrix}+J^t\cdot Q\cdot \begin{pmatrix}u\\ v\end{pmatrix}+h=0\longrightarrow\frac{5+\sqrt{17}}{2}u^2+\frac{5-\sqrt{17}}{2}v^2+\begin{pmatrix} \frac{-1-\sqrt{17}}{\sqrt{34+2\sqrt{17}}}& \frac{\sqrt{17}-1}{\sqrt{34-2\sqrt{17}}}\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}u\\ v\end{pmatrix}-2=0
> \\
> \longrightarrow \frac{5+\sqrt{17}}{2}(u^2+\frac{\frac{-1-\sqrt{17}}{\sqrt{34+2\sqrt{17}}}}{\frac{5+\sqrt{17}}{2}}u)+\frac{5-\sqrt{17}}{2}(v^2+\frac{ \frac{\sqrt{17}-1}{\sqrt{34-2\sqrt{17}}}}{\frac{5-\sqrt{17}}{2}}v)-2=0\longrightarrow \\
> \longrightarrow \frac{5+\sqrt{17}}{2}(u^2+\frac{3-\sqrt{17}}{\sqrt{34+2\sqrt{17}}}u)+\frac{5-\sqrt{17}}{2}(v^2+\frac{3+\sqrt{17}}{\sqrt{34-2\sqrt{17}}}v)-2=0\longrightarrow \\
> \longrightarrow \frac{5+\sqrt{17}}{2}(u^2+\frac{3-\sqrt{17}}{\sqrt{34+2\sqrt{17}}}u+\frac{17-4\sqrt{17}}{68}-\frac{17-4\sqrt{17}}{68})+\frac{5-\sqrt{17}}{2}(v^2+\frac{3+\sqrt{17}}{\sqrt{34-2\sqrt{17}}}v+\frac{17+4\sqrt{17}}{68}-\frac{17+4\sqrt{17}}{68})-2=0\longrightarrow \\
> \longrightarrow \frac{5+\sqrt{17}}{2}((u+\frac{3-\sqrt{17}}{2\sqrt{34+2\sqrt{17}}})^2-\frac{17-4\sqrt{17}}{68})+\frac{5-\sqrt{17}}{2}((v+\frac{3+\sqrt{17}}{2\sqrt{34-\sqrt{17}}})^2-\frac{17+4\sqrt{17}}{68})-2=0\longrightarrow \\
> \longrightarrow \frac{5+\sqrt{17}}{2}(u+\frac{3-\sqrt{17}}{2\sqrt{34+2\sqrt{17}}})^2-\frac{17-3\sqrt{17}}{136}+\frac{5-\sqrt{17}}{2}(v+\frac{3+\sqrt{17}}{2\sqrt{34-\sqrt{17}}})^2-\frac{17+3\sqrt{17}}{136}-2=0$ 
> Now: $\begin{pmatrix} w\\ z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}u+\frac{3-\sqrt{17}}{2\sqrt{34+2\sqrt{17}}}\\ v+\frac{3+\sqrt{17}}{2\sqrt{34-\sqrt{17}}} \end{pmatrix}$, and so:

$\frac{5+\sqrt{17}}{2}w^2+\frac{5-\sqrt{17}}{2}z^2=2\frac{1}{4}\Longrightarrow \frac{w^2}{\frac{9}{10+2\sqrt{17}}}+\frac{z^2}{\frac{9}{10-2\sqrt{17}}}=1$
And so we get that the canonic version of $3x^2+2y^2-4xy+x-2=0$ is $\frac{w^2}{\frac{9}{10+2\sqrt{17}}}+\frac{z^2}{\frac{9}{10-2\sqrt{17}}}=1$ in the {$z,w$} axis. 
For refrence, those are the shapes in demsos:
[image]

**What do I do from here?**

Comment: You went into a lot of detail on the algebra there, but it might be more helpful to concentrate on why you were doing those steps. Ultimately, you've rotated and translated the ellipse so that its axes match the coordinate axes, and its centre is $O$. This is often useful for geometry questions, but here, the original question asked about integer lattice points in the original coordinate system. So, what you *could* do next is apply the same transformation to the integer lattice; but I'm not very sure how this will help. What are your thoughts on that?

Comment: The simplest approach to the original problem, by the way, is probably to 1) note we're dealing with an ellipse, which means the possible solution space is bounded; 2) observe that the $x$ values lie between $-1$ and $2$ and 3) check the four possible $x$ values for integer solutions. It's not very elegant, but is all that's needed in this case.

Comment: @ChrisLewis Is there a way to calculate the point that has the lowest $y$ in the ellipse? If yes, how?

Comment: Sure. The key question is, how many times does the line $y=Y$ intersect the ellipse? It's either $0$, $1$ or $2$, and we're interested in when it's $1$. (This should hopefully make you think about the roots of quadratic equations, and their discriminants.) With that in mind, fix $Y$ and treat the equation as a quadratic in $x$: $3x^2+(1-4Y)x+2Y^2-2=0$. The discriminant of this is $(1-4Y)^2-24(Y^2-1)$, and for the equation to have exactly one root, the discriminant should be zero - you can solve for $Y$ from there.

Comment: So is it practically the same way that I mentioned in the beginning of the question? OK, Thanks! BTW, so you think that finding the canonic version of the equation won't help me to finding those coordinates - $y=-2.33\backslash 1.33$?

Comment: Ah, I think I missed that that's what you were doing in your question. I don't quite see how transforming to canonical form would help very much; you're not interested in a property of the ellipse in that orientation, you're looking at a property in the untransformed setting. Converting to canonical form is useful for properties like, say, getting the major and minor axes, but you're looking at the max and min $y$ coordinates in a particular orientation. If you remove that orientation, the question no longer makes sense.

Comment: And I have two more questions. 1) How can I find the vertices of the ellipse? 2) if the equation was a parabola, how would we calculate the answer then? @ChrisLewis